# Displaying content in tabs using loop in XSLT

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am trying to display data with tab using XSLT. What i want is to display different subcategories in different tabs. For example: The main category is Vehicle and the subcategories are car, bus and so on. I want car in tab1, bus in tab2 and so on. I want car tab and content to be the active one. So far i have is car in tab and then display the content and below content showed a bus in tab and the content and below is another tab and content.I know it has something to do with JavaScript and am not good in that. If anyone has suggestions ,i appreciate your help.

```
        <div id="subcat-carousel-wrapper">

                <ul class="tabs">
                  <xsl:for-each select="childCategories/category">
                    <li id="tab1" class="active">
                      <a href="#tab1">
                        <h2>
                          <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='DisplayName']"/>
                        </h2>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <a class="series-name" style="display:none">
                        <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='Id']"/>
                      </a>
                      <xsl:variable name="subcatPages" select="ceiling(count(childProducts/product) div 4)"/>
                      <div class="carousel-mask" >
                        <div class="productsDiv" runat="server">

                          <xsl:for-each select="childProducts/product">
                            <xsl:if test="position() mod 4 = 0">
                              <div class="subcat-carousel-product-box">
                                <a class="subcat-links">
                                  <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                    <xsl:variable name="productId" select="properties/property[@name='Id']"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('../Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?pid=', $productId)"/>
                                  </xsl:attribute>
                                  <div class="subcat-thumbnail">
                                    <xsl:if test="Images/category/childProducts/product/properties/property[@name='Gallery_thumbnail']">
                                      <xsl:variable name="imageUrl" select="Images/category/childProducts/product/properties/property[@name='Gallery_thumbnail']"/>
                                      <img class="carouselThumb">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                          <xsl:value-of select="concat($MediaUrl, $imageUrl)"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="title">
                                          <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='DisplayName']"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                                          <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='DisplayName']"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                      </img>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                  </div>
                                  <h2>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="properties/property[@name='DisplayName']"/>
                                  </h2>
</xsl:for each>
</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: You still haven't shown us what the XML input looks like. Also the XSL you posted contains a number of errors in that it is missing a lot of closing tags.

Comment: You might want to split this into two questions: 1) What should the HTML/javascript look like? and 2) How do I generate that HTML using XSLT? Until you figure out the answer to 1, trying to answer 2 is pretty pointless.